# Zend File Transfer: Problem when uploading a single image

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-file

I cannot understand how ->isuploaded() works. I am suppose to upload six images to display on my index page. Now the problem is, in my update function, if I upload only one or two image $upload->isUploaded() returns a false value, but if I decide to update all six of them it returns a true value. How do I deal with this problem? Am i missing out something here?

Here is my zend file transfer upload

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
$upload->addValidator('Count', false, array('min' =>1, 'max' => 6)) 
               ->addValidator('Size', false, array('max' => '1Mb'))
               ->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array('minwidth' => 50,
                                                        'maxwidth' => 1000,
                                                        'minheight' => 50,
                                                        'maxheight' => 1000));

if ($upload->isUploaded()) $hasImage = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

By default Zend guess all uploaded files are invalid even if just one of submitted form file fields was empty.
Zend docs are suggest to override this behavior by calling `isValid()` method *before* `receive()`.
So I'm not sure if suggest best solution, but it works for me:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
$upload->setDestination( 'some your destination' );
if( $adapter->isValid( 'your form file field name' ) ){
    $adapter->receive( 'your form file field name' );
}
```

And so on with every file field name. Wrap in `foreach` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [isValid()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_File_Transfer_Adapter_Abstract.html#Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Abstract%3a%3aisValid%28%29) instead.

```
if ($upload->isValid()) {
    // success!
} else {
    // failure!
}
```

Once you know your upload passed the validators, then start processing the images.

Comment: @Niklas Yup tried that too. But it is not working. It is just not ready to set $hasImage as true if I don't upload 6 images.

Comment: @Varun `$upload->isValid()` is returning `false`?

Comment: @Nklas Yes! as it is not setting the $hasImage to true. But yes if I upload all of them it sets it to true.

Comment: @Varun Can you please post the rest of your code then, because there is something else wrong if it isn't validating it.

Comment: @Niklas According to documentation "sUploaded($files = null): This method will check if the specified files have been uploaded by the user. **This is useful when you have defined one or more optional files**. When no files are specified, all files will be checked." What does optional files suppose to mean? How do I define optional files?

Comment: @Varun post the rest of your code and it would be easier to fix the issue

Comment: `if ($hasImage) 
            {
                echo "Inside Bol Has Image";
                $files = $upload->getFileInfo(); 
                print_r($files);
//And I try to save it in the database here
             }  ` So it should display $files and the echo statement! but it doesn't.

Comment: @Varun was more looking for the stuff before that... as $hasImage is always false as you said.